# How can i add a class to an <a> with a specific href in php?

Tags: php, navbar, element, nav

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
$("ul").find("a[href=filename]").addClass('active');
```

with an ul in my header.php:

```
<li><a href="index.php">Főoldal</a></li>
<li><a href="gallery.php">Galéria</a></li>
<li><a href="games.php">Játékok</a></li>
<li><a href="contacts.php">Elérhetőségeink</a></li>
<li><a href= "about.php">Rólunk</a></li>
```

I spent hours with this. I just can't add a class to an anchor tag, based on the site i am currently on.

Comment: let us know what is the output of `console.log(filename);`.Ad it after `var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);` and check your browser console and let us know

Comment: Doing `$("ul > li > a[href='"+filename+"']").addClass('active')` would probably work, though it's better to add the class in PHP since PHP knows which section it is in more accurately (e.g. if you're planning to use rewrites and such)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$uri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

With this you get the URI, like "*/index.php*", now you need to compare it with the url in your  tag. Even though I'd recommend using JS/jQuery, like:

```
var current_path_url=window.location.pathname;

$('a[href="'+current_path_url+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables aren't expanded inside quoted strings, you have to use concatenation (unless you want to use ES6 template literals, but older browsers don't support them).

```
$("ul > li > a[href=" + filename + "]").addClass('active');
```